# Print difference of column1 if column2 values are same

Tags: shell

I have a file something like this:

```
19:32:19        4599544
19:32:22        4599544
19:33:07        4599545
19:33:11        4599545
19:33:58        4599546
19:34:01        4599546
```

1st column is time(hh:mm:ss). If the second column values are same. I need to print the difference of the column1 values..
i.e., I need output something like this:-

```
3  4599544
4  4599545
3  4599546
```

Comment: Your syntax requires quite some cognitive processing before it is clear what it is you want. Maybe you could rephrase it.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    function to_seconds(hms,     t) {
        split(hms, t, /:/)
        return (t[1]*3600 + t[2]*60 + t[3])
    }
    $2 in times {print to_seconds($1) - times[$2], $2}
    {times[$2] = to_seconds($1)}
' << DATA
19:32:19        4599544
19:32:22        4599544
19:33:07        4599545
19:33:11        4599545
19:33:58        4599546
19:34:01        4599546
DATA
```

```
3 4599544
4 4599545
3 4599546
```